# Large XML dataset parsing with filters

Tags: xml, filter, xml-parsing, elementtree, large-data

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tracking xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" update="2017-01-23T14:41:26">
  <Match id="2019285" dateMatch="2016-09-13T18:45:00" matchNumber="13">
    <Competition id="20159" name="UEFA Champions League 2016/2017" />
    <Stadium id="85265" name="Estádio do SL Benfica" pitchLength="10500" pitchWidth="6800" />
    <Phases>
      <Phase start="2016-09-13T18:45:35.245" end="2016-09-13T19:31:49.09" leftTeamID="50157" />
      <Phase start="2016-09-13T19:47:39.336" end="2016-09-13T20:37:10.591" leftTeamID="50147" />
    </Phases>
    <Frames>
      <Frame utc="2016-09-13T18:45:35.272" isBallInPlay="0">
        <Objs>
          <Obj type="7" id="0" x="-46" y="-2562" z="0" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="105823" x="939" y="113" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250086090" x="1194" y="1425" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250080473" x="37" y="2875" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250054760" x="329" y="833" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="98593" x="-978" y="654" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250075765" x="1724" y="392" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="53733" x="-4702" y="45" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250101112" x="54" y="1436" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="250017920" x="-46" y="-2562" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="105588" x="-1449" y="209" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="250003757" x="-2395" y="-308" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="101473" x="-690" y="-644" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250075775" x="2069" y="-895" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="103695" x="-1654" y="-2022" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250073809" x="4712" y="-16" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="63733" x="-2393" y="1145" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250015755" x="-42" y="31" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250055905" x="1437" y="-2791" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250042422" x="1169" y="-1250" sampling="0" />
        </Objs>
      </Frame>
      <Frame utc="2016-09-13T18:45:35.319" isBallInPlay="0">
        <Objs>
          <Obj type="7" id="0" x="-46" y="-2558" z="0" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="105823" x="938" y="113" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250086090" x="1198" y="1426" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250080473" x="36" y="2874" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250054760" x="330" y="833" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="98593" x="-980" y="654" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250075765" x="1727" y="393" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="53733" x="-4712" y="44" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250101112" x="54" y="1435" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="250017920" x="-46" y="-2558" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="105588" x="-1449" y="209" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="250003757" x="-2396" y="-310" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="101473" x="-692" y="-645" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250075775" x="2071" y="-896" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="103695" x="-1655" y="-2016" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250073809" x="4712" y="-17" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="1" id="63733" x="-2395" y="1145" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250015755" x="-42" y="29" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250055905" x="1435" y="-2793" sampling="0" />
          <Obj type="0" id="250042422" x="1169" y="-1250" sampling="0" />
        </Objs>
      </Frame>
    </Frames>

  </Match>
</Tracking>
```

I have a large XML dataset that I have been able to parse into a data frame. However, this process takes extremely long and I have to perform some filtering afterward so the process is extended. Would anyone know how to filter during the parsing stage in order to speed up all processes to get a data frame that is relevant?

My current code is this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

d = defaultdict(list)

root = ET.parse('filename.xml').getroot()

root = ET.parse('UCL1617_M13_2019285_BEN_BES_PosData_Live (sample).xml').getroot()

for ent in root.findall('./Match//Frame'):
    Frame = ent.attrib['utc']
    for entry in ent.findall('Objs/Obj'):
        d[Frame].append(entry.attrib)

df = (pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(value)
                 .assign(Frame=key) 
                 .filter(['id','Frame','x','y','z']).
                 for key, value in d.items()),
                axis=0) #concatenate on the columns axis
     )
```

I would like to load the lines that are only id == 0 and Frame split seconds == 272

Please see the data below: